# dataframe.groupby.agg TypeError: _agg_2dim() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregate

I am trying to group by departement and keep the columns with the corresponding longitudes and latitudes to the city with the maximum populations within the department. Any idea why this doesn't work?

```py
popDEP = pop.copy().groupby("dep", as_index=False)[["dep","lon","lat","total"]].agg({'total': ['max']})

Population ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maintrain.py", line 43, in <module>
    popDEP = pop.copy().groupby("dep", as_index=False)[["dep","lon","lat","total"]].agg({'total': ['max']})
  File "/home/ludo915/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 951, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ludo915/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 410, in _aggregate
    result = _agg(arg, _agg_2dim)
  File "/home/ludo915/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 383, in _agg
    result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
TypeError: _agg_2dim() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: This is minimal and complete, I cannot upload data here.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have a column name that is 'total' and again you are trying to create a column with the same name i.e 'total' here agg({'total': ['max']}).

So change the column name.

Comment: If so where do I specify I want the max to be chosen within the "total" columns?